# First time using Protocols - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, protocols

This is my first time using Protocols in Objective-C, and I'm running into a trouble: Here's what I've got:

I have a ReportsReceiver.h:

```
@protocol ReportsReceiver


-(void)receiveData:(NSArray *)theData;

@end
```

I have a MyController.h:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController<ReportsReceiver,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

}
@end
```

I have a MyController.m with the implemented method:

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSArray *)theData {
    NSLog(@"received some data!");
}
```

And then I have a class AllUtilities.m with the declaration:

```
Protocol *receiverProtocol;
```

AllUtilities.m also contains a method to initialize the protocol:

```
- (void)initProtocol {
    receiverProtocol = @protocol(ReportsReceiver);

}
```

And then later on in AllUtilities.m I make the call:

```
[receiverProtocol receiveData:anArray];
```

Which crashes the application with the error:

```
2011-01-07 11:46:27.503 TestGA[91156:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x9c28c of class 'Protocol' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2011-01-07 11:46:27.504 TestGA[91156:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x9c28c of class 'Protocol' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the part about protocols in the [Objective-C guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) once more :) I think you don’t really understand how protocols work. This is what you want:

```
// DataProducer.h
@protocol DataConsumer
- (void) handleData: (NSArray*) data;
@end

@interface DataProducer
@end

// DataProducer.m
@implementation DataProducer

- (void) generateDataAndPassTo: (id <DataConsumer>) consumer
{
     NSArray *data = …;
     [consumer handleData:data];
}

// SomeController.h
#import "DataProducer.h"

@interface SomeController <DataConsumer>
@end

// SomeController.m
@implementation SomeController

- (void) requestData
{
    // The producer is of type DataProducer.
    // Where you get it is irrelevant here.
    [producer generateDataAndPassTo:self];
}

- (void) handleData: (NSArray*) data
{
    NSLog(@"Got data.");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

A protocol is, in essence, a contract that says, for example, "an object conforming to the `ReportsReceiver` protocol must implement the `receiveData:` method".

So, MyController.h promises that `receiveData:` will be present, and MyController.m fulfills the promise. So far so good.

Now, your `receiver` variable doesn't care exactly what type of object the receiver is, so long as it conforms to the `ReportsReceiver` protocol. The way you declare that is:

```
id<ReportsReceiver> receiver;
```

...and in your initialization you might say:

```
receiver = myController;
```

Then invoke it like:

```
[receiver receiveData:anArray];
```

Comment: what do you mean "in your initialization"? What exactly is myController?

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding the NSObject protocol to your own protocol. The warnings you are getting are methods from NSObject.

```
@protocol ReportsReceiver <NSObject>

-(void)receiveData:(NSArray *)theData;

@end
```

When declaring an object that implements a protocol, it should be more like:

```
id<ReportsReceiver> receiverProtocol;
```

or

```
ReceiverClass<ReportsReceiver> *receiverProtocol;
```

in the case that you create an object (ReceiverClass) that implements the ReportsReceiver protocol.

You assign a class that implements a protocol in the same way you assign any other class:

```
ReceiverClass<ReportsReceiver> *receiverProtocol;
- (void)initProtocol {
    receiverProtocol = [[ReceiverClass alloc]init];
}
```

The @protocol directive begins declaring a protocol, not casting to one. Check out the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html) for how to use them.

Comment: Adding NSObject to the protocol isn't necessary; he's only getting those errors because he's trying to invoke a "Protocol" object, which is not useful.

Comment: So in my AllUtilities I have to declare a protocol for each class I have that I want to implement that protocol? I don't understand that.

Comment: No, you define the protocol once. Then implement that one protocol on any classes you want.